# Counter in PHP and preview with whatsapp facebook and twitter

Tags: php, counter, preview, whatsapp

I have a counter in a PHP page. Let's say I have a var=1. I want when the user visit it that var=var-1. It will be set to 0. And it is working well.

The problem is when I share the website on Whatsapp or on Facebook, the preview that generate those app, are visiting the page and affecting my var.

How can I know when the page is being visiting directly or it is being visiting to generate a preview link?

Comment: It's an interesting question made so poorly.

Comment: man, is not the words, it is the problem, english is not my first language

Comment: Just look for the user agents of twitter facebook etc. and check for them when the are visiting in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can check from where the request is coming using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - it will return the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. You can check if the referer is Facebook or Whatsapp and disable your variable counter.

Comment: do you know the referers of those apps?

Comment: Referers value will contain `facebook.com` or `whatsapp` in it.

Comment: if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'facebookexternalhit')) {... }
this is working for facebook, but i need whatsapp and twitter too.

Comment: AFAIK, Twitter uses the User-Agent of Twitterbot (with version, such as `Twitterbot/1.0` ) when crawling pages to find Twitter Cards markup.

Comment: For Whatsapp, it's something like this: `'WhatsApp/2.10.750 Android/4.2.1 `

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((strstr(strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'facebook')) || (strstr(strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'whatsapp')) || (strstr(strtolower ( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'twitter')))  {
...
}
```

Comment: Side note: `strstr` has a case-insensitive sibling: [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)